# Do any Jewish sources give a non-literal interpretation of the census in Bamidbar?

Tags: tanach, midrash, archaeology, biblical-criticism, census

Are there any classical commentators that state that "elef" didn't literally mean 1 thousand, or something else to that effect, that would result in a smaller number? I am reading [Ani Maamin by Rav Joshua Berman](https://korenpub.com/products/ani-maamin-biblical-criticism-historical-truth-and-the-thirteen-principles-of-faith), which makes this case on logistical grounds, as well as various statements that indicate that the Canaanim had a larger population than us and several other things, and then says that the text can be read non-literally through linguistics, but do any Rishonic sources corroborate this or are open to such readings?

Comment: Did you check how many elefs and how many meahs are counted in the census Numbers chapter 1? I count 55 meahs and 598 elefs. Though the listed total is 5 meahs and 603 elefs.

Comment: I think that is one of the weakest points of Berman's book. Eleph is always placed after meah and eser. It is clearly a base 10 system. I doubt any one else will read this way because it is simply a bad read

Comment: Do you mean by rounding up or more significant non-lliteralness?

Comment: Either, although especially the latter.